# Using Outlook templates in the Access Database

Tags: forms, ms-access, templates

My organization uses 5 Outlook Templates for plagiarism notifications.   My goal is to be able to click a "button" (or whatever works) in my Access database and have that outlook template open. My Google searches and Youtube searches are resulting in ways to add an attachment to a record.  I guess I either don't know the proper term to use or Access isn't designed for this.

Experience Level:   I'm a newbie with access/VBA.  I can do/understand basic concepts and tasks.

I created a table.  I only attached the "1st" template until I see if this works.
Table Name:  PlagiarismInfractionsT

| ID | Infractions | Field1 | Links |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1st | Plagiarism Notification- 1st Infraction.oft | #https://forms.office.com/r/vW7AEscAdq# |
| 2 | 2nd |  |  |
| 3 | 3rd |  |  |
| 4 | 4th |  |  |
| 5 | 5th |  |  |

Field1 is the attachment field
The Links field is not part of this question

In my form, I tried using the "attachment" control.  I now realize this is to allow users to UPLOAD files.

My goal is to have a button for each attached file from the table.   I'd be open to using a combo box to select the infraction number and have the attachment from the table open as well.

Results of what I tried:
The database is trying to add a record to this file, not open the template that I want to use.
Not sure if this is possible but thought I would ask.

My workaround is to use the "link" control and provide a hyperlink to the table.  Then staff can click on the attachment field and, using the dialogue box, select open.  This works but I have many staff who are not technical at all and was hoping to have some sort of button.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't understand the question; for instance, you could just wrap the link in the button click event and click it using vba if you wanted